# Managing thread exception using a Task

Tags: c#, .net, task, threadpool

I'm creating a task in my main thread in order to manage my thread. My purpose is to benefit from AggregateException, so I want my task to return that exception once an exception occurs in a thread that is started in the task as shown in the codeblock below.

```
public void ReportGeneratorFiveThreadTest()
{
    var logger = new Log4NetLogger(typeof(ReportGeneratorThreadTest));
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        var estimatedReportSize = EstimatedReportSize.Normal;
        var thread = new ReportGeneratorThread(logger, new ReportGenerator(20), estimatedReportSize);
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            thread.Start();                    
        });
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    try
    {
       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
       Debug.WriteLine("Tasks are completed");
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + v.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

GenerateReport() method is called by the started thread and it throws the exception defined in this method.

```
public void GenerateReport()
{
    var didwork = false;
    try
    {
        didwork = this.reportGenerator.GenerateReport(this.estimatedReportSize);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.log.LogError(ReportGenerator.CorrelationIdForPickingReport, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error during report generation."), 0, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!didwork)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.ReportGenerationInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the exception is not presented in the task an thus, the aggregateexception does not take place in this case. Is it possible to present this innerexception, which occurs in the thread in the task, so aggregateexception is triggered ?.

**UPDATE----------------------**

I have modified my code with following:

```
 public void Start()
 {
        this.running = true;
        this.t = Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            this.GenerateReport();
        });
        try
        {
            Task.WaitAny(this.t);
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + v.Message);
            }
        }
 }
```

and with:

```
  public void GenerateReport()
    {
        var didwork = false;            
        try
        {
            didwork = this.reportGenerator.GenerateReport(this.estimatedReportSize);                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.log.LogError(ReportGenerator.CorrelationIdForPickingReport, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error during report generation."), 0, e);
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!didwork)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.ReportGenerationInterval);
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

and it still does not catch the AggregateException even though the InvalidOperationException is thrown in GenerateReport() method.

Comment: throw the exception after you have caught it and logged.  ie GenerateReport needs to actually throw.  Alternatively GenerateReport could actually return something (ie null or the exception) and you could have Task<Exception> and iterate through the return values.

Comment: That does not help either. It seems like the main thread completes the Tasks.WaitAll method before the thread has thrown the exception

Comment: There is code we cant see between your 'outer' creation of the tasks and the GenerateReport method, my guess is you are catching somewhere else, if not post the full code chain.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must rethrow the exception in the `catch` block of the `GenerateReport` method

```
public void GenerateReport()
{
    var didwork = false;
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.log.LogError(...);
        throw; // Important!
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!didwork)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly you shouldn't use Thread inside Task. Use only Tasks

```
public void ReportGeneratorFiveThreadTest()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // No need thread here
            GenerateReport();
        });
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```